# How do I evaluate this surface integral?

Tags: vector-analysis

A vector field is given by $ = [2y + 3, xz, yz − x]$.
Evaluate $\int F \cdot \text{d}S$
where where $S$ is the surface defined by a cylinder of unit
radius centered around the origin, with $−1 < z < 1$.

Comment: I assume that $S$ and $F$ are both vectors?

Comment: @kvantour F is a vector field and S is the scalar equation x^2 + y^2 = 1 to define the cylinder of unit radius

Comment: Are you sure that $dS$ is not a vector (norm times surface)? Should the result be a scalar or a vector?

Comment: Yeah dS is the normal vector times the surface, and the result should be a scalar

Answer (score 0):

The value of the surface-element $\textrm{d}\textbf{S}$ can be written as $\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{S}=\boldsymbol{n}\;\textrm{d}\theta\;\textrm{d}z$ with $\boldsymbol n=\left(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\right)$. Using the substitutions $x=\cos\theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$, one obtains:

$$ \int_\Omega\boldsymbol F\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol S =\int_\Omega\boldsymbol F\cdot\boldsymbol n\;\mathrm{d}\theta\;\mathrm{d}z $$
$$ \int_\Omega\boldsymbol F\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol S = \int_{-1}^1\mathrm{d}z\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\;\cos\theta\left(3+(2+z)\sin\theta\right)=0$$